# How to hanlde more user information (Field) With JHipster UAA

Tags: jhipster, user-management

I have 2 microservice, 1 registry, 1 gateway and 1 uaa that run made by JHipster. now in first contract with JHipster UAA, I can't understand how to handle more field on user registration?! where user data store?

I know it's on UAA but can't find any entity to add my field that gateway can detect. I guess that field must be added to User class in UAA and then in gateway add Its corresponding fields;

Do you work with Jhipster UAA? Can share your experiment with me? Is there any advance tutorial on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is the straightforward and the recommended way of solving this:

the direct approach is

1. add your field to `User` class
2. add it also to `UserDTO` and `ManagedUserVM`, to make it available at `UserResource` and `AccountResource`
3. apply changes to `UserService`
4. add the field to liquibase (src/main/resources/config/liquibase)

This way is fast, but you break compatibility to upgrade to newer UAA from JHipster, as you overwrite default classes.

The better approach is, if you add a new entity, say `UserAdditionalInfo` or something like this, what is in a one-to-one relationship to the user. Here you can add as many fields you want using the entity sub-generator, and still be open to upgrades from JHipster.

Comment: I want to add UserAdditionalInfo, how I must to do? add like entity or by adding manually?

Comment: I would just generate it with the entity generator, and force a nested creation. That means, every time when a user is created, it automatically has a UserAdditionalInfo bound to it...